# How to hide only Site Action using SecurityTrimmedControl

Tags: 2010

I have a portal and in master page I was being asked to hide the whole ribbon so i did this. But since then i am having so many problems like if i have a custom list with a document to attach option the modal dialog opens but no buttons inside and similarly i have a link which opens a custom aspx form embed inside webpartpage the modal dialog doesnt appear ..only site collection administrator can see the modal dialogues. Someone advised me not to hide the ribbon and only hide site action. So how to hide only site action?

```
Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl2" runat="server" Permissions="ManageWeb">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("s4-ribbonrow").style.display = "block";
    </script>
</Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl2" runat="server" PermissionsString="ManageSubwebs">

<<SharePoint:SiteActions control>>

</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

Reference: [How to remove Site Actions and View All Site Content](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/11/how-to-remove-site-actions-and-view-all.html).

Comment: Benny i guess ive messed the masterpage..i did hide the ribbon long time back and now i dont remember what did i do exactly to hide it as i am unable to unhide my ribbon. please see my edited question

Comment: @user342944 Maybe start over and take a new copy of the v4.master would do the trick?